# Inheriting a type declaration in the presence of templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inheritance

Is there a way to declare types in a base class template and re-use those definitions in the child class template?

For example, consider the following attempt:

```
template <typename T_>
struct A {
    using T=T_;
};

template <typename T_>
struct B: public A<T_> {
    T a;
};
```

The compiler complains that using the type `T` in the definition of `B` is illegal. It doesn't wait for instantiation to see that this type is inherited from A. So, is there a way to declare types in a base class template and re-use those definitions in the child class template?

Comment: GCC 5 tells you what to do: `(perhaps ‘typename A<T_>::T’ was intended)`

Comment: Yes, I know about this fix. But this undermines the purpose of putting the type declaration in the base class...

Comment: There are a few other fixes, but any of those also undermine that "purpose" in the sense that you apparently mean that.  Nothing you can put in just the base class will let you use the type in the derived class without extra work in the derived class.

Comment: @JSF May be I can somehow include all those type declarations in a batch? I mean, come on, inheritance is about re-use!

Comment: FWIW: this compiled fine in VS2012 and even worked 'as expected' without any modifications (i.e. declared `B<int> b` and could access `b.a` as an `int` type) .. as an aside: I know your example is simplistic, but couldn't you just declare your `a` member in your `B` struct as the template parameter, since you have to pass it to your `A` parent for the `T` to be valid anyways in your using declaration ... e.g. `template <typename T_> struct B : public A<T_> { T_ a; };` ?

Comment: @txtechhelp As you noted, the example is simplistic. The parent declares other types as well which all the children want to re-use.