# Inhering type declarations in a hierarchy of templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, using, code-duplication

Consider this:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
    using MyType1 = ...;
    using MyType2 = ...;
    using MyType3 = ...;
    using MyType4 = ...;
    using MyType5 = ...;
    ...
};

template <typename T>
struct B: A<T> {
    using MyType1 = typename A<T>::MyType1;
    using MyType2 = typename A<T>::MyType2;
    using MyType3 = typename A<T>::MyType3;
    using MyType4 = typename A<T>::MyType4;
    using MyType5 = typename A<T>::MyType5;
    ...
};

template <typename T>
struct C: A<T> {
    using MyType1 = typename A<T>::MyType1;
    using MyType2 = typename A<T>::MyType2;
    using MyType3 = typename A<T>::MyType3;
    using MyType4 = typename A<T>::MyType4;
    using MyType5 = typename A<T>::MyType5;
    ...
};

... // Many more classes in the hierarchy 
    // with all the type declarations duplicated in each of them.
```

Is there any way this can be made shorter?

A related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33985950/2725810) was asked, but did not make the point of how bad the duplication was and did not receive any replies.

Comment: Are you using MSVC? That code shouldn't compile anyway because `A<T>::MyTypeN` is a dependent type, it would need to be `typename A<T>::MyType1`.

Comment: Fixed, thank you. No, I am using `gcc`.

Comment: No sure what do you want to do. Why not just use `typename A<T>::MyType1`, or `typename B::MyType1`, `typename C::MyType1`... ?

Comment: Because it's verbose. In the real program, `A` and `T` are not one-letter names.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to import or redeclare the typenames in the derived class, you need at least to tell the compiler to look up the typenames in the derived class hierarchy.

You can do this using the name of the derived class as the qualifying scope:

```
typename B::MyType1 x;
```

If `B` is a long name, or you want to be able freely to move code between `B` and `C`, you can conventionally add a typedef at the head of the class:

```
template <typename T>
struct B: A<T> {
    using ThisType = B;
    // ...
    typename ThisType::MyType1 x;
};
```