# A bug in doxygen? (shows type declarations as inherited even in the presence of templates)

Tags: c++, doxygen

As detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33985950/2725810) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37206745/2725810), a `using` type declaration that appears in the template base class in not available in the child template. However the documentation generated by `doxygen` (version 1.8.10) shows such declarations as inherited. Furthermore, when `C<T>` inherits from `B<T>`, which in turn inherits from `A<T>`, the same declaration may be shown in `C<T>` twice -- both as inherited from `B<T>` and as inherited from `A<T>`.

Is this a bug? Is there a way to work around it?

Comment: From my experience, doxygen works pretty bad with C++ templates.

Comment: Agreed. Doxygen gets most things right, but will occasionally lose its mind when it comes to complicated C++ code.

Comment: _"Is this a bug?"_ What would you expect as an answer? Yes? _"Is there a way to work around it?"_ Probably not. How would you like to fix the rendering?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This situation is very strange. Many projects have been documented with `doxygen`. The users don't mind occasional lapses in documentation?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning _"The users don't mind occasional lapses in documentation?"_ Well, you learn to live with it. Questionable is why you're asking here, instead of reporting the bug at Doxygen's site?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Because I could not imagine that such things could persist...

Comment: Maybe [check if the bug is already known](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/buglist.cgi?product=doxygen&bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED) and if it isn't, [report it](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=doxygen). SO is not really suitable as a 3rd party bug tracker.

Comment: @nwp I turned to SO mainly for a work-around, such as a configuration change. The question "is this a bug?" was just to make sure, almost rhetorical...